# group then compute delta on a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am using pandas to process a dataset (see samples below), where `t` and `tu` are timestamp (epoch in seconds and microsecond respectively). and `br` and `bw`  are cumulative values at the sample time. I'd like to perform two actions:

- split groups based `A` and `B` (there maybe many)
- for each group, I'd like to compute the delta of `br` and `bw`, e.g. `br[n] - br[n-1]`

I am having difficulty to figure this out, any help is appreciated.

```
 # data as dictionary

 data = {0: {'group': 'A', 't': 1532973555, 'tu': 319007, 'br': 28, 'bw': 32},
 1: {'group': 'B', 't': 1532973555, 'tu': 319638, 'br': 100, 'bw': 200},
 2: {'group': 'A', 't': 1532973999, 'tu': 320594, 'br': 75, 'bw': 86},
 3: {'group': 'B', 't': 1532973999, 'tu': 320652, 'br': 300, 'bw': 500}}

# read into dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index")
```

Comment: `df.groupby('group').br.diff()
`

Answer (score 0):

To compute differences in a dataframe, you can use the `diff` method. In you case it would be something like that:

```
df.groupby('group')['br'].diff() 

0      NaN
1      NaN
2     47.0
3    200.0
Name: br, dtype: float64
```

Comment: is there a way to keep group info? i.e. #2 (47) output is from group A, #3 (200) is from group B ... this seems necessary if extra steps are to be performed on the diff.  thx

Comment: If you assign the Series created this way to a new column of your dataframe, it will be appended so that you will keep all the informations present in your dataframe.